# Avoid global conflict with Google Analytics in embeddable JS module

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We provide our clients, who are eCommerce website owners, with a JS module that they can embed in their website. It's basically a `<script src=...>` they put in their HTML that loads our JavaScript and shows our UI upon checkout, similar to [this](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial#embedding).

Now since I'm loading Google Analytics module independently (and according to [their docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)):

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

// ...
</script>
```

I'm risking a conflict with the hosting website's own Google Analytics module.

Even if I follow the [renaming the ga object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/renaming-the-ga-object) instructions:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','analytics');
</script>
```

(note the `'analytics'` change)

It's still risky, because it depends on the `i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r` bit, which is technically  `window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=customGlobalName`. When the analytics.js script loads, it looks in `window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']` for the global name and uses it. But then it means the I'd override the hosting website's `window['GoogleAnalyticsObject']` value, even if it defaults to `ga`.

I saw that for their [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/), they allow a better way to [renaming the gtag object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/renaming-the-gtag-object), but it's still in alpha stage :(.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nope, I don't understand what the problem is. Why are you calling your variables the same as googles? If you wrap your js in proper closures the chances of a conflict seem pretty minimal to me. Basically I don't understand why this is an issue or why you need to rename the `ga` object

Comment: @Liam, he is worried that including the GA snippet a second time will overwrite the existing ga object and thus reset its configuration options (so the clients own tracking will be disrupted).  That is not actually a problem, since Google wrote the code so that you can have multiple trackers, and that it aborts attempts to run the snippet a second time, but it is a valid concern.

Comment: Yeah I got that from your answer. Thanks for clarifying anyway @EikePierstorff

Comment: So @EikePierstorff, shall I not condition the loading of my analytics.js script only if it was not already loaded by the hosting website? Are you saying that Google's script knows to not load itself twice?

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to have multiple separate ga objects (renaming is just possible in case the ga name is taken by some other script) since you can create separate instances of the tracker object by using a tracker name:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'embeddableJSmoduleTracker');
```

and then prefixing all your calls with the respective name

```
ga('embeddableJSmoduleTracker.set','userId','abcde');
ga('embeddableJSmoduleTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

The tracker name makes sure that all tracker instances have their own configuration (just make sure you do not forget the name prefix or you will write to the default tracker).

To minimize interference you might also consider using a [custom cookie name](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#cookieName) (must be set when creating the tracker).